# How can I pause this redstone wall rotator as nessecary?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

<sup>Back...with another Minecraft device.</sup>

First off, I remember seeing a device like this on Reddit/YouTube a long time ago, and I've since forgotton how it was done.

The way the device works ins shown in the first video, while the in-place build is shown on the second video. I want to be able to push a button and the pistons pules for 10 times and then automatically stop rather than having to flip the lever. In the example I saw before I think there was another set of blocks on the end that rotated, although some were made of glass so when it got to a certain level it would cut the circuit and stop the wall.

Comment: these videos no longer exist.  Do you have screen shots or similar you could post to clarify this question?

Comment: @John - I closed the original YouTube channel a while back and I thought I updated the post. Apparently not so I've re-linked the videos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Ronan's answer will probably suffice in this situation, it will not be completely accurate. If you want a device that will pulse exactly 10 times, you can create a sort of counter with pistons. Here's the basic design:

[image]

This device uses a set of pistons to pulse a set number of times, then stop. Here's what the piston device looks like:

[image]

The glass block does not conduct redstone power, so the repeater does not power "through" it. All the stone blocks do conduct power, though, so those will be powered by the repeater. The pistons are set up to cycle through the blocks once the system is started, and it will stay on until the glass block becomes active.

[image]

These are the device's input and output. The lever overrides the glass block and turns the device on. The redstone line on the left will then pulse exactly 10 times before stopping. Note that the device *will not stop* if the lever remains on, so it might be a good idea to hook up a pulse limiter/extender to the input to keep the machine from malfunctioning.

Additionally, the speed of the pulses are determined by the clock seen in the first picture. By changing how fast the clock moves, you can adjust how often the output pulses. Note that I used all 1-tick repeaters to keep the length of the tick at about 2 redstone ticks, not extended to 4. If you're making it run more slowly, though, that's not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

What you do is instead of the starting lever you have a button hooked up to the S (set) of a [RS-NOR](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_circuits#RS_NOR_latch_and_Input_Stabilizers) latch so after it is pressed it stays on forever, but also have it power a string of repeaters leading to the R (reset) which will turn off the circuit again after a set amount of time.